# Install Intel Wifi AX200

Tags: drivers, iwlwifi, firmware

I have a Intel Wifi AX200 as far as I can tell. I have seen more topics about this but I'm not really sure what to do.

On this page:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless-networking.html

There are the following steps:

> ```
> To install firmware:
>
> 1. Copy the files into the distribution-specific firmware directory, /lib/firmware.
> 2. If the directory doesn't work, refer to your distribution documentation.
> 3. If you configure the kernel yourself, make sure firmware loading is enabled.
> ```

Does this mean I have to put it in `/lib64/firmware` since I have a 64bit OS?

Also how do I know if the directory works or not? Is it just a single reboot?

The adapter is working on windows, is there any risk of breaking that (I have dual boot)?

I also readed somewhere that after kernel 5 is installed that it should be supported natively. So I prefer that over drivers.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.03, a folder `/lib64` already exists but there is no firmware folder in there. `/lib/firmware` does exist.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Please click [edit] and tell us which version of Ubuntu or other distro you are using, and its release number, too. Also, is there already a folder named /lib64/firmware ?.

Comment: The firmware is not an issue. You need a kernel upgrade. Anyway all firmware should be in `/lib/firmware` it is not 64 vs 32 sensitive.

Comment: @Pilot6 The link you posted worked! Thank you so much, I expected this to be so much harder.